# How do I draw a pair of concentric circles with graphviz?

Tags: graph, graphviz

Something really simple, like a big circle 'A' and a smaller circle 'B' inside it. Surprisingly no examples have nested circles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Graphviz doesn't draw circles; it draws graph nodes of different shapes. You can get a node consisting of two concentric circles by setting the node's shape=doublecircle. Alternatively, you can draw two nodes with shape=circle at the same position. For a basic catalogue of node shapes, see https://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/shapes.html